# Are these questions quality enough for this site?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, quality-evaluation, question-quality

I just went through our Community Eval and discovered 2 questions that were pulled into this list that left a sour taste in my mouth.

- 1 [Merry Go Round](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/7926/is-the-merry-go-round-of-life-from-howls-moving-castle-a-song-in-the-public-d)
- 2 [Lost Girl](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/7959/which-episode-is-the-tick-tick-boom-image-captured-from)

The Merry Go Round questions seems like basic **trivia** about music and knowing whether or not is public domain doesn't seem to strike any 'appreciation' value with me and should be closed.  Though we have had a lot of debate over music questions to begin with, this is a clear example of a poor one to me.

---

The Lost Girl question, to me, is trivia, nothing more.  The answer is solved in less than 5 words and doesn't add any appreciation for the title nor does it show why the .gif is important to begin with.

Both are examples of questions that seemingly slip through the cracks that we have to be more careful of.  If there's no objection, these will be closed shortly.

Comment: 2 is kind of an identify this question.  I wouldn't object both of them being closed however.

Comment: The Lost Girl question was not liked by me and i want to close it previously but my personal rule of not posting a close vote to upvoted question stopped me.

Comment: @AnkitSharma just because a question has an upvote doesn't mean that you shoulnd't post a close vote on it.  if you think it doesn't belong then VTC, even if others don't agree.

Comment: @DForck42 i keep in mind from next time

Comment: **Close** and **Close** [immediately!](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/306/should-movie-trivia-questions-be-closed)

Answer (score 1):

As per my point of view, both of them can be closed. As they are not helpful for future visitor and i don't think that the second question to be like identify this question and should be closed too.

Answer (score 1):

Number 1 is more of amusic question than a movie/tv question, and should be closed as off-topic.  As for number 2, it's not a very compelling question or of high interest to me, but I can't see it as off-topic.  It's answer could be improved upon to explain how they found the answer.